# Android: Numerous overlays slowing down map movement

Tags: android, performance, overlay, android-mapview

I have numerous Overlays added to a MapView. When I move, zoom in, or zoom out of the MapView the overlays cause a significant lag before the map responds to the action. Is there any way I can minimize this delay?

I saw that someone else suggested combining all the overlays into one large overlay for a similar problem. If something like that would work, how would I combine my array of overlays into a single overlay?

I also saw that it may improve performance to draw all the lines specified in the overlays on a bitmap and then overlay the bitmap instead. If this is the best option, then how would I go about implementing it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need any more information or code, then please ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have numerous Overlays added to a MapView. When I move, zoom in, or zoom out of the MapView the overlays cause a significant lag before the map responds to the action. Is there any way I can minimize this delay?

Have fewer and less-complicated overlays. Use Traceview to determine exactly where your problem is. If it is that one of your existing `draw()` methods is slow, you will need to fix that before worrying about combining overlays. If the excess time seems to be in overlay management in `MapView`, then consolidating your overlays into fewer overlays may have benefit.

> how would I combine my array of overlays into a single overlay?

Refactor the code into a single overlay class. Beyond that, we cannot help you, since we do not know much of anything about your overlays, other than that they are "numerous".

> If this is the best option, then how would I go about implementing it?

Create a [bitmap-backed `Canvas`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#Canvas%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29), draw your lines on it, then draw the resulting `Bitmap` in your overlay in `draw()`, I presume.

Comment: Ok, I'll figure out exactly where it is slowing down with Traceview, and then I'll report back in a day or two probably with more questions. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I have another question. I'm trying to draw a line from one `GeoPoint` to the next `GeoPoint` in an array. How am I supposed to draw lines created from GeoPoints on a bitmap-backed `Canvas` considering that I can't use `projection.toPixels()`?

Comment: @BrianEcker: This does not really follow from your original question. Please ask new questions rather than use comments as an open-ended discussion board. That being said, `projection.toPixels()` works just fine, but you will then have to translate the pixels from screen coordinates to `Canvas` coordinates. If your resulting bitmap would happen to be drawn in the upper-left corner, the pixel coordinates would be the same on the `Canvas` as on the screen. If your bitmap will be offset from the upper-left corner, you need to adjust the `toPixels()` values to match.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm still new here. Thanks